# input number accepts trailing dashes

Tags: html, html-input

How can I block input number of accepting trailing dashes (values like "10-" or "10-7")? If you enter wrong format Input doesn't give you any value.

`<input name="Number" type="number">`

Comment: What number do you want to be able to enter? The default number input will allow a lot of things most people don't need (e.g. `e`)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function validate(evt) {
  l = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value.length;
  if(l === 0 && String.fromCharCode(evt.keyCode) === '-') return
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode( key );
  var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
  if( !regex.test(key) ) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type='text' onkeypress='validate(event)' />
```

Comment: Ok, let me clarify that I would like to still be able to enter negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without validating the value of the input.

Since it is a string representing the number there is no way to be sure that string may be representing numeric values or not.

The Permitted attributes will not give you the ability to validate the value of the number input control.

One way to do this with the help of JavaScript could look like this.

```
var numInput = document.querySelector('input');

// Listen for input event on numInput.
numInput.addEventListener('input', function(){
    // Let's match only digits.
    var num = this.value.match(/^\d+$/);
    if (num === null) {
        // If we have no match, value will be empty.
        this.value = "";
    }
}, false)



<input name="Number" type="number" min="0" >
```

Answer (score 0):

bind keydown event to the input, if keyCode == 189 or keyCode == 69, preventDefault()

Comment: how is this different than Yernar's answer